# how to use jquery deferred with vktemplate / queuing ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates, jquery-deferred

Using [vktemplate](http://www.eslinstructor.net/vktemplate/) isn't quite working when I try to use jquery deferreds. Since the vktemplate makes an ajax call of its own, the deferred gets resolved before vktemplate completes its work, and its optional callback. How can I set up vk so that the promise doesn't get resolved until after these two things happen?

```
$(document).on('click', '.ajax', function() {
    $.when(ajax1('<p>first</p>'), 
           ajax2('<p>second</p>'), 
           ajax3('<p>third</p>'))
     .then(function(results1, results2, results3) {
        console.log(results1);
        $('.document').append(results1);
        $('.document').append(results2); 
        $('.document').append(results3);         
        alert('all ajax done');
    });
});

function ajax1(data) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'templates/test_template.tmpl',
        data: "data=" + data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (returnedData) {

            $('#resultsDiv').vkTemplate('templates/test_template.tmpl', returnedData, function () {
                //vk callback
                //possibly call my resolve here?
            });
        }
    });
}

function ajax2(data){//more of the same}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since vkTemplate returns nothing you need to manually create a deferred and resolve it in success callback with required data.

```
function ajax1(data) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'templates/test_template.tmpl',
        data: "data=" + data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (returnedData) {

            $('#resultsDiv').vkTemplate('templates/test_template.tmpl', returnedData, function (el, data, context) {
                dfd.resolveWith(context, [$(el)]);
            });
        }
    });

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Comment: Resolves a deferred with context and arguments. 
http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/

Comment: Actually, where do these arguments in the callback come from? `(el, data, context)` are they a part of vktemplate or do they come from deferred object?

Comment: It's interesting because my `success` callback uses the parameter `returnedData`, but both `returnedData` and `data` show the same object when I print them to the console. Do you know why that is? Thanks!

Comment: vkTemplate passes data it was called with
`if(callback) {callback(elm, jsonObj, context);}`